# What would be the best way to perform operations against a significant number of rows from one df to one row from another?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have df1:

```
    A     B      C     D
0   4.51  6.212  3.12  1
1   3.12  3.444  1.12  1
2   6.98  7.413  7.02  0
3   4.51  8.916  5.12  1
....
n1 ~ 2000
```

and df2

```
    A     B      C     D
0   4.51  6.212  3.12  1
1   3.12  3.444  1.12  1
2   6.98  7.413  7.02  0
3   4.51  8.916  5.12  1
....
n2 = 10000+
```

And have to perform an operation like:

```
df12 = 

df1[0,A]-df2[0,A]     df1[0,B]-df2[0,B]     df1[0,C]-df2[0,C]....
df1[0,A]-df2[1,A]     df1[0,B]-df2[1,B]     df1[0,C]-df2[1,C]
...
df1[0,A]-df2[n2,A]    df1[0,B]-df2[n2,B]    df1[0,C]-df2[n2,C]
...
df1[1,A]-df2[0,A]     df1[1,B]-df2[0,B]     df1[1,C]-df2[0,C]....
df1[1,A]-df2[1,A]     df1[1,B]-df2[1,B]     df1[1,C]-df2[1,C]
...
df1[1,A]-df2[n2,A]    df1[1,B]-df2[n2,B]    df1[1,C]-df2[n2,C]
...
df1[n1,A]-df2[0,A]    df1[n1,B]-df2[0,B]    df1[n1,C]-df2[0,C]....
df1[n1,A]-df2[1,A]    df1[n1,B]-df2[1,B]    df1[n1,C]-df2[1,C]
...
df1[n1,A]-df2[n2,A]   df1[n1,B]-df2[n2,B]   df1[n1,C]-df2[n2,C]
```

Where every row in df1 is compared against every row in df2 producing a score.

What would be the best way to perform this operation using either pandas or vaex/equivalent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your output `df12` will have ~20,000,000+ rows and 4 columns ?

Comment: In this example yes, but it was just a rough demonstration of the scale. This can be scaled back, as column 'A' will only be matched if df2['A'] = df1['A'] +/- 0.5.

Comment: I am thinking about numpy broadcasting. That's why I ask about number of rows. I am worried that ~20 million rows after the broadcasting will cause memory error. However, it depends on how big memory of your system. Give @QuangHoang's solution a try to see if your system is able to handle numpy broadcasting that big.

Comment: @AndyL. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=20000000+*+4+*+32+bits&oq=20000000+*+4+*+32+bits) say that is only 320 MBs. So it's not too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasting is the way to go:

```
pd.DataFrame((df1.to_numpy()[:,None] - df2.to_numpy()[None,...]).reshape(-1, df1.shape[1]),
             columns = df2.columns,
             index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index,df2.index))
            )
```

Output (for `df1` the three first rows, `df2` the two first rows):

```
        A      B    C    D
0 0  0.00  0.000  0.0  0.0
  1  1.39  2.768  2.0  0.0
1 0 -1.39 -2.768 -2.0  0.0
  1  0.00  0.000  0.0  0.0
2 0  2.47  1.201  3.9 -1.0
  1  3.86  3.969  5.9 -1.0
```

Comment: In this example, would it support combination operations? Say df12['A'] = df1['A'] - df2['A'] and df12['D'] = df1['D'] == df2['D'] (Boolean).

Comment: No, you would need to work on the column separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would use openpyxl

This loop would do

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=minr, min_col=starting col, max_col=finshing col, max_row=maxr):
    for cell in row:
        df1 = cell.value
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=minr, min_col=starting col, max_col=finshing col, max_row=maxr):
    for cell in row:
        df2 = cell.value
```

from here you want do what , create new values ? put them where? the code here points on them

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, that vaex can actually solve quite memory efficient (although we should be able to require practically no memory in the future).

Let's start creating the vaex dataframes, and increase the numbers a bit, 2,000 and 200,000 rows.

```
import vaex
import numpy as np
names = "ABCD"
N = 2000
M = N * 100
print(f'{N*M:,} rows')
400,000,000 rows

df1 = vaex.from_dict({name + '1': np.random.random(N) * 6 for name in names})
# We add a virtual range column for joining (requires no memory)
df1['i1'] = vaex.vrange(0, N, dtype=np.int32)
print(df1)
#      A1                   B1                   C1                   D1                  i1
0      5.863720056164963    3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784   0.1482153863632898  0
1      5.873731485927979    5.669031702051764    5.696571067838359    1.0310578585207142  1
2      4.513310303419997    4.466469647700519    5.047406986222205    3.4417402924374407  2
3      0.43402400660624174  1.157476656465433    2.179139262842482    1.1666706679131253  3
4      3.3698854360766526   2.203558794966768    0.39649910973621827  2.5576740079630502  4
...    ...                  ...                  ...                  ...                 ...
1,995  4.836227485536714    4.093067389612236    5.992282902119859    1.3549691660861871  1995
1,996  1.1157617217838995   1.1606619796004967   3.2771620798090533   4.249631266421745   1996
1,997  4.628846984287445    4.019449674317169    3.7307713985954947   3.7702606362049362  1997
1,998  1.3196727531762933   2.6758762345410565   3.249315566523623    2.6501467681546123  1998
1,999  5.013902261001965    0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243   2.6801177594876218  1999

df2 = vaex.from_dict({name + '2': np.random.random(M) * 6 for name in names})
df2['i2'] = vaex.vrange(0, M, dtype=np.int32)
print(df2)
#        A2                   B2                   C2                  D2                  i2
0        2.6928366822161234   3.227321076730826    5.944154034728931   3.3584747680090814  0
1        4.824761575636117    2.960087600265437    3.492601702004836   1.054879207993813   1
2        4.33510613806528     0.46883404117516103  5.632361155412736   0.436374137912523   2
3        0.0422709543055384   2.5319705848478855   3.5596949266321216  2.5364151309685354  3
4        2.749335843510271    3.5446979145461146   2.550223710733076   5.02069361871291    4
...      ...                  ...                  ...                 ...                 ...
199,995  5.32205669155252     4.321667991189379    2.1192950613326182  5.937425946574905   199995
199,996  0.10746705113978328  4.104809740632655    0.6282195590464632  3.9603843538752974  199996
199,997  5.74108180127652     3.5863223687990136   4.64031507831471    4.610807268734913   199997
199,998  5.839402924722246    2.630974123991404    4.50411700551054    3.0960758923309983  199998
199,999  1.6954091816701466   1.8054911765387567   4.300317113825266   4.900845720973579   199999
```

Now we create our 'master' vaex dataframe, that requires *no memory at all*, it's made of a virtual column and two expressions (stored as virtual columns):

```
df = vaex.from_arrays(i=vaex.vrange(0, N*M, dtype=np.int64))
df['i1'] = df.i // M  # index to df1
df['i2'] = df.i % M   # index to df2
print(df) 
#            i          i1    i2
0            0          0     0
1            1          0     1
2            2          0     2
3            3          0     3
4            4          0     4
...          ...        ...   ...
399,999,995  399999995  1999  199995
399,999,996  399999996  1999  199996
399,999,997  399999997  1999  199997
399,999,998  399999998  1999  199998
399,999,999  399999999  1999  199999
```

Unfortunately vaex cannot use these integer indices as lookups for joining directly, it has to go through as hashmap. So there is room for improvement here for vaex. If vaex could do this, we could scale this idea up to trillions of rows.

```
print(f"The next two joins require ~{len(df)*8*2//1024**2:,} MB of RAM")
The next two joins require ~6,103 MB of RAM

df_big = df.join(df1, on='i1')
df_big = df_big.join(df2, on='i2')
print(df_big)
#            i          i1    i2      A1                 B1                   C1                  D1                  A2                   B2                   C2                  D2
0            0          0     0       5.863720056164963  3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784  0.1482153863632898  2.6928366822161234   3.227321076730826    5.944154034728931   3.3584747680090814
1            1          0     1       5.863720056164963  3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784  0.1482153863632898  4.824761575636117    2.960087600265437    3.492601702004836   1.054879207993813
2            2          0     2       5.863720056164963  3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784  0.1482153863632898  4.33510613806528     0.46883404117516103  5.632361155412736   0.436374137912523
3            3          0     3       5.863720056164963  3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784  0.1482153863632898  0.0422709543055384   2.5319705848478855   3.5596949266321216  2.5364151309685354
4            4          0     4       5.863720056164963  3.362898169138271    3.2880444660598784  0.1482153863632898  2.749335843510271    3.5446979145461146   2.550223710733076   5.02069361871291
...          ...        ...   ...     ...                ...                  ...                 ...                 ...                  ...                  ...                 ...
399,999,995  399999995  1999  199995  5.013902261001965  0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243  2.6801177594876218  5.32205669155252     4.321667991189379    2.1192950613326182  5.937425946574905
399,999,996  399999996  1999  199996  5.013902261001965  0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243  2.6801177594876218  0.10746705113978328  4.104809740632655    0.6282195590464632  3.9603843538752974
399,999,997  399999997  1999  199997  5.013902261001965  0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243  2.6801177594876218  5.74108180127652     3.5863223687990136   4.64031507831471    4.610807268734913
399,999,998  399999998  1999  199998  5.013902261001965  0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243  2.6801177594876218  5.839402924722246    2.630974123991404    4.50411700551054    3.0960758923309983
399,999,999  399999999  1999  199999  5.013902261001965  0.07240435410582324  0.8744364486077243  2.6801177594876218  1.6954091816701466   1.8054911765387567   4.300317113825266   4.900845720973579
```

Now we have our big dataframe, and we only need to do the computation, which is using virtual columns, and thus require no extra memory.

```
# add virtual colums (which require no memory)
for name in names:
    df_big[name] = df_big[name + '1'] - df_big[name + '2']
print(df_big[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']])
#            A                     B                     C                     D
0            3.17088337394884      0.13557709240744487   -2.6561095686690526   -3.2102593816457916
1            1.038958480528846     0.40281056887283384   -0.20455723594495767  -0.9066638216305232
2            1.5286139180996834    2.8940641279631096    -2.344316689352858    -0.2881587515492332
3            5.821449101859425     0.8309275842903854    -0.2716504605722432   -2.3881997446052456
4            3.1143842126546923    -0.18179974540784372  0.7378207553268026    -4.87247823234962
...          ...                   ...                   ...                   ...
399,999,995  -0.30815443055055525  -4.249263637083556    -1.244858612724894    -3.257308187087283
399,999,996  4.906435209862181     -4.032405386526832    0.2462168895612611    -1.2802665943876756
399,999,997  -0.7271795402745553   -3.51391801469319     -3.765878629706985    -1.930689509247291
399,999,998  -0.8255006637202813   -2.5585697698855805   -3.629680556902816    -0.41595813284337657
399,999,999  3.318493079331818     -1.7330868224329334   -3.4258806652175418   -2.220727961485957
```

If we had to do this all in memory, how much RAM would that have required?

```
print(f"This would otherwise require {len(df_big) * (4*3*8)//1023**2:,} MB of RAM")
This would otherwise require 36,692 MB of RAM
```

So, quite efficient I would say, and in the future it would be interesting to see if we can do the join more efficiently, and require practically zero RAM for this problem.